# Print whole column numbers with results query from each of that number separated by comma

Tags: sql, sql-server

The first query:

```
 SELECT [name]
 FROM [MyDB].[dbo].[abcCategories]
 where categoryID in (SELECT categoryId FROM [MyDB].[dbo].[CategorySets]
                      where setId='123456')
```

I got

```
keyword1
keyword2 
keyword3
keyword4
keyword5
```

The number `'123456'`
is getting from this second query:

```
SELECT [setId]   
FROM [MyDB].[dbo].[CategorySets]
```

this will returns all number in one column:

```
12
123
1234
12345
123456
1234567
12345678
```

So now I need to do first query for all values in second query.
I want to print all that numbers in one column and results of first query in the next column correspondingly and separated by comma:

```
12       | abc, xyz, asdf,abc
123      | ..., ...,....,...
1234     | asfa,fdasf,asdfsa,sdfa
.....    |
123456   | keyword1,keyword2,keyword3,keyword4,keyword5
......   |
12345678 | keyword6, keyword 7
```

How could I archive that ?

Comment: Are you using SQL Server?

Comment: Yes, I am using MS SQL Server

Comment: Coalesce might be what you are looking for. Only, use it in a variable like this: SELECT @variable = ISNULL(@variable, '') + Column + (some theory) FROM ThisTable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work.. Use For XML PATH for concatinating NAME column with comma separated. And Stuff for removing first comma.

```
;WITH CTE AS(
SELECT C.[setId] , AC.[name]
FROM [MyDB].[dbo].[abcCategories] AC
INNER JOIN [MyDB].[dbo].[CategorySets] C ON AC.categoryID= C.categoryId

)
SELECT C1.[setId]
, STUFF((SELECT ','+C2.[name] FROM CTE C2 
WHERE C1.[setId] = C2.[setId] FOR XML PATH('') ),1,1,'')
FROM CTE C1
```

Comment: This help to put commas to the first query. However my question is a little bit more complex. I need to do first query for all number in second query (it will replace " setId ='123456' "  by " setId in 'sencond query' "). also need to print all columns of 2nd query together with the result above.

Comment: This is the core idea, how you can handle the case. I am not having your tables and data. But you can achieve it by modifying the above query with some other columns.

Comment: Actually I know how to separate the results with comma. But how to combine two query results ?

Comment: The above code will give result after combining only. Like your desired oput `123456   | keyword1,keyword2,keyword3,keyword4,keyword5`. If you provide your actual schema with data will give correct requirement

Comment: I tried, it doesn't give two columns together, only for 1 value '123456'. I provided all required info : first query, second query. how the results returns for each. Now I am asking how to combine two of them.

Comment: Then you can just remove where clause from CTE.  remove `WHERE C.setId ='123456'`. Check with my edited answer. Actually I was copied your code from your question. So I din't removed it   @user1314404

Comment: Yes, I add in distinct that helps. Thank you :)

Comment: Happy to help.. :)